# Get AWS to automatically attach EC2 Volume to Ubuntu instance at startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to attach an EBS volume not a snapshot as a persistent store for my spot instances.  I understand how to manually attach the volume, mount it and get it to survive reboots but how would I get it to automatically get attached at startup?

Is there something I could do in the user data at launching the instance?

Presently I have a ami that I run as a spot instance.  I have a separate volume that persists and is used for both input to the instance and to save results.  I only ever have one instance up at a time.  The ami mounts the drive at /data. For the mount to survive reboots, I have edited `/etc/fstab` to include:

`UUID=MY_VOLUME_UUID  /data  xfs  defaults,nofail  0  2`

***Again Edited to show Passatizhi's Solution***

I added the following to the Configure Instance Details > Advanced Details > User data part of the EC2 launch wizard:

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) 
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//') 
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-myVol12345 --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --device /dev/sdf 
sleep 10 
sudo mkdir -p /data 
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 /data
```

Note:
I needed to add the full path to aws to get it to work. Also as the ami already has the /data setup I don't need the `sudo mkdir -p /data`

Comment: By “at startup”, you mean at instance launch?

Comment: @hephalump yes when the instance launches

Comment: I want to clarify, **one** volumе is mount for several instances at the same time? You can create a volume and attach it in the aws console. Is this not suitable?

Comment: @Passatizhi I edited my question to be more specific but I was not asking how to attach the volume to multiple instances only **automatically** one volume to one instance at creation/1st startup.

Comment: https://www.karelbemelmans.com/2016/11/ec2-userdata-script-that-waits-for-volumes-to-be-properly-attached-before-proceeding/

Comment: @Passatizhi Ok that would help with the drive not mounting if I am slow or forget but that doesn't automatically attach the volume. I do appreciate the help!

Comment: Try to use aws cli in user data. Aws cli is already installed in ami.

Comment: Create IAM role for EC2. And try this INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//')
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-1234567890 --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --device /dev/sdf
sleep 10
mkdir -p /data
mount /dev/nvme1n1 /data

Comment: @Passatizhi Thank you I will try.  Sorry it took a while but I was flying back from Asia.  I will respond tomorrow after I try it out.

Comment: @Passatizhi I again edited my question to show what I did.  The problem is that when I put it into the User data it doesn't attach the drive.  The other commands seem to run though. If I wait for the instance to start I can manually enter those exact commands and it will attach and mount the drive.

Comment: @PaulO     #!/bin/bash
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//')
/bin/aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-0fdb738415896f8f6 --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --device /dev/sdf
sleep 10 
sudo mkdir -p /data 
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 /data       Try /bin/aws instead aws. I used t3.small, so /dev/nvme1n1.

Comment: @Passatizhi  It worked!!!!  I have aws installed at /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/aws so I used that.  If you want to provide the code as a solution I will choose it as the correct answer.  Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash INSTANCE_ID=$(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) 
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//')
/bin/aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-0fdb738415896f8f6 --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --device /dev/sdf
sleep 10
sudo mkdir -p /data
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 /data
```

Try /bin/aws instead aws. I used t3.small, so /dev/nvme1n1